# Sending one audio input to two outputs in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, cable

I have bought a new piano. I want to do two things with it and, using VB-Audio virtual cable, have found a solution to either one:

Listen to it on my headphones:

- In the sound settings under "Listen", send `Piano input > Headset output`

Mix my headset mic and the piano so that people can hear it on Discord:

- Send `Piano input > VB Audio virtual cable`
- Send `Headset input > VB Audio virtual cable`
- On discord, use `VB Audio virtual cable` as my input

However, I can't do these at the same time, because I can only send Piano Input to one output at the same time. What solution is there?

Answer (score 0):

The VB-Audio virtual cable works the way you described. You either can talk or use VB to re-route a single device into virtual microphone input.

If you see some YouTubers what setup they have, many of them are actually using small mixing device for this purpose when they are having soundboards or pianos.

The only software I know of (I am sure there are more) which can allow to talk and play something at the same time is [Soundpad](https://store.steampowered.com/app/629520/Soundpad/).